# Query Excel C# for Searching

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I have connected an Excel sheet with a C# Form application. Now I would like to query this excel sheet to search for an entry which has the desired value or else a similar value

Example search for "1" and the output would be "1", "11", "01", "10" etc...

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table]
WHERE Number = [value]
```

What do I have to change so that the output would be like I want it?

Thank you

Comment: We really need more context and the surrounding code, so we know how you connecting and performing other operations for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looking for like:

```
SELECT Number 
  FROM [table]
 WHERE Number Like '%1%'
```

Comment: Works however I found that for the way I want it functioning it would be too complex. Thank you for your response I will mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: Actually it was a small mistake from my end. Your solution is great :) Thanks again!!!